# Ошибка “Uh-oh! Unable to provision site” при попытке создать новый сайт WordPress в программе Local

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost

Выдает следующую ошибку “Uh-oh! Unable to provision site”  при попытке первый раз создать новый сайт WordPress в программе localhost.

[image: ошибка создания нового сайта]

Ранее работал через "opensever", подобных проблем не возникало.

Добавлял в исключения брандмауэра Windows 10 и саму программу и папку целиком.

Коллеги просто нажимали "ok" и создание продолжалось в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Вы наверное имели ввиду [Local](https://localwp.com/), а не localhost.

Answer (score 0):

special characters, часть адреса на русском языке
https://community.localwp.com/t/special-characters-not-supported-on-windows-username-password/14419/85

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)